# php strtotime puzzle - daylight savings?

Tags: php, time, strtotime, dst

### PHP CODE

```
$t = strtotime( '2012-09-21T03:00:00+00:00 America/Chicago' );
$t2 =  date('c',$t);
echo $t2;
```

---

### OUPUT

```
 2012-09-20T23:00:00-04:00
```

---

### QUESTION

Chicago's timezone is UTC-5, why don't I get `2012-09-20T22:00:00-05:00` as the result?

Comment: Welcome to the DST.  It's more f'd up than Evander Holyfield's check book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtotime` converts to a Unix timestamp. `date` will convert the timestamp to a string using the current time zone. Try setting your time zone first.

```
$t = strtotime( '2012-09-21T03:00:00+00:00 America/Chicago' );
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$t2 =  date('c',$t);
echo $t2;
```

Comment: +1.  Current versions of PHP will even warn you if you haven't set a default timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer my question, but I did the following to fix it:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$t = strtotime( '2012-09-21T03:00:00+00:00' );
$t2 =  date('c',$t);
echo $t2;
```

Output: `2012-09-20T22:00:00-05:00`

Comment: We were posting at the same time. :)